# how get data from selected row datatable.js

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

in this way I fetch the data

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {

    "ajax": {
      "method":"POST",
      "url":"exampleurl.php"
      },
      "columns":[
          {"data":"title"},
          {"data":"description"},
          {"defaultContent": "<button  id='show-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#show-modal' class='btn btn-primary'>show</button>"}
      ]
} );

 $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {


  console.log( table.row( this ).data() );

      });
});
```

I have seen answers where they propose to use this

```
table.row( this ).data()
```

but  not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a variable to the DataTable instantiation, and change `table.row( this ).data()` to `table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "method":"POST",
            "url":"exampleurl.php"
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data":"title"},
            {"data":"description"},
            {"defaultContent": "<button  id='show-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#show-modal' class='btn btn-primary'>show</button>"}
        ]
    } );

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {


        console.log(table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data());

    });
});
```

Comment: tells me table is not defined

Comment: how did you fetch your data? @MichelNovellino